# Populate a value in one feature class from value in another feature class using SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have two feature classes:

**COH_Address** (points)

**TAXLOTS_NOAT** (polygons)

I am trying to find the best code for using a cursor to run through **TAXLOTS_NOAT**, grab the value for **TLNO**, and populate the field **TLNO_GIS** in the **COH_Address** feature class the **TAXLOTS_NOAT** feature class field **TLNO**

```
import arcpy
# Local variables:
COH_Address = "C:\\Users\\mclbr\\Desktop\\AddressTest.gdb\\Places\\COH_Address"
TAXLOTS_NOAT = "C:\\Users\\mclbr\\Desktop\\AddressTest.gdb\\TAXLOTS_NOAT"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(TAXLOTS_NOAT, "TAXLOTS_NOAT")  
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("TAXLOTS_NOAT", "", "", "TLNO", "")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(COH_Address, "COH_Address")  
for row in rows:  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management    ("COH_Address", "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", "TAXLOTS_NOAT", "", "NEW_SELECTION")  
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("COH_Address", "TLNO_GIS", "%(row.TLNO)", "PYTHON")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) is what you're after. It will assign attributes from one feature class to another based on spatial relationship.

```
outFc = "C:\\Users\\mclbr\\Desktop\\AddressTest.gdb\\COH_ADDR_SpatialJoin"
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis (COH_Address, TAXLOTS_NOAT, outFc)
```